# How do I strip quotes and commandline arguments out from a file path in C#?

Tags: c#, command-line, filenames, quotes, strip

I have filepaths in quotes with empty spaced foldernames like this with at least two command line parameters of different length and value appended:

**"C:\My Program\Sample Folder\SubFolder2\MyApp1.exe" -parameter13XY1 -parameter101XZ2**

I would like to have only the filename without quotes and without commandline arguments:

**C:\My Program\Sample Folder\SubFolder2\MyApp1.exe**

I would search functions like "*StripQuotes*" and "*StripCommandLineArgs*" in the framework, but I didn't find anything similar, since the framework has almost everything missing what would be needed.
As for quotes it would maybe do a "Replace", but the commandline arguments can't be sorted out that way. The filename also contains spaces, so it is not possible to work with Split() as it would cut a part of the filename out.

In the end I would like to have only the filename without quotes and commandline arguments. Note that the filename can also contain empty spaces and hyphens and both combinations of it, like this:

**"C:\My Program - Win64\Sample-Folder\Sub -Folder3\My App55- .exe -parameter1 -parameter2 para3"**

I have no idea how to find out only the valid path in such cases. There could be also five commandline arguments attached or even 10.

Comment: You can use `replace` and `split` methods of string.

Comment: Are you sure your last example is valid? I've never seen the command line parameters inside the quotes before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression `"^\"([^\"]*)\".*$"` to get the content of the quoted string, like this:

```
var s = "\"C:\\My Program\\Sample Folder\\SubFolder2\\MyApp1.exe\" -parameter13XY1 -parameter101XZ2";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, "^\"([^\"]*)\".*$", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Here is a [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/3xvKD).

Answer (score 1):

A slightly heavier answer is to use a command line parsing library like http://commandline.codeplex.com/. It handles all the parsing for you without needing to deal with regular expressions.

Comment: @feedwall Agreed. However, if you are already using it, it's an easy stretch, for example.

Answer (score 0):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) can take a parameter for the character to split on - so if you try this:

```
var array = filename.Split('"');
```

You should get back an array with two elements:

```
array[0] = "C:\My Program\Sample Folder\SubFolder2\MyApp1.exe"
array[1] = "-parameter13XY1 -parameter101XZ2"
```

Comment: Ah, that'll be the one before the first " then - did you look in element 1?

Answer (score 0):

The very rough & quick solution:

```
string cmd = "\"C:\\My Program\\Sample Folder\\SubFolder2\\MyApp1.exe\" -parameter13XY1 -parameter101XZ2";
var allStrings = cmd.Split(new char[] {'"'} );
```

Comment: var means that compiler will infer the type automatically. in this example it could be 'string[]' (as this is what Split method returns) but var is perfectly fine.